# How do each entity be generated in their respective database?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There are two entities: `Profiles` and `Cars`.

The entity `Profiles` is related to a table in the database `X` and the entity `Cars` is related to a table in the database `Y`.

The Doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: cars
        connections:
            profiles:
               driver:   pdo_mysql
               host:     "%database_host_profiles%"
               port:     "%database_port_profile%"
               dbname:   "%database_name_profiles%"
               user:     "%database_user_profiles%"
               password: "%database_password_profile%"
               charset:  UTF8
            cars:
               driver:   pdo_mysql
               host:     "%database_host_cars%"
               port:     "%database_port_cars%"
               dbname:   "%database_name_cars%"
               user:     "%database_user_cars%"
               password: "%database_password_cars%"
               charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        connection: cars
        auto_mapping: true
```

When I run the following command, the two entities are generated in the same database (cars):

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

How do each entity be generated in their respective database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define entity managers in the orm section and to map the bundles you want to manage with the not default em :

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        profiles:
            auto_mapping: true
            connection: default
        cars:
            connection: other_connexion
            mappings:
                AcmeBundle1: ~
                AcmeBundle2: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just prepend the table name with the database that the entity is mapped to, just like so:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Database_Name.Table_Name")
 */
class MyEntity
{
    // ...
}
```